# Extract Google Search Result Redirects

Tags: python, curl, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I have read several stackoverflow posts on how to [extract the URLs of Google search results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371655/extract-google-search-results), and have written a similar implementation using python, curl and beautifulsoup.

My question is, how can I extract the Google redirect links (such as when you right click on a result and select 'copy link location')?

Answer (score 0):

Google has made results page interactive through ajax. So BeautifulSoup won't be able to extract the links directly. I suggest to read the page first into a string so that it has all HTML, than you can use BeautifulSoup to extract the links.