# Python Script to Get 150 Google Search Result

Tags: python

I need to get first 15 page google search result with the help of python. I tried with this answer [Extract Google Search Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371655/extract-google-search-results). But i did't get the prior result. I need 150 search result's, raw links with python. If anyone knows, give me the solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That kind of question is realy epic. Ganeshgm7, could you please add some example of your tries to your question? That would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got 150 search results this way :

```
import sys # Used to add the BeautifulSoup folder the import path
import urllib2 # Used to read the html document

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ### Import Beautiful Soup
    ### Here, I have the BeautifulSoup folder in the level of this Python script
    ### So I need to tell Python where to look.
    sys.path.append("./BeautifulSoup")
    from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

    ### Create opener with Google-friendly user agent
    opener = urllib2.build_opener()
    opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]

    ### Open page & generate soup
    ### the "start" variable will be used to iterate through 10 pages.
    for start in range(0,15):
        url = "http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com&start=" + str(start*10)
        page = opener.open(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

        ### Parse and find
        ### Looks like google contains URLs in <cite> tags.
        ### So for each cite tag on each page (10), print its contents (url)
        for cite in soup.findAll('cite'):
            print cite.text
```

You just need to install `BeautifulSoup` before : `pip install BeautifulSoup`.

The code came from the link you cited : [Extract Google Search Results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371655/extract-google-search-results)

Comment: Yes . It's working. Thank you. But when checking it with manually it slightly differ. But i don't know the reason for that.?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [SERP API](https://serpapi.com/) using the [Python wrapper](https://github.com/serpapi/google-search-results-python) Repo

The instructions are fairly simple:

```
pip install google-search-results
```

and the usage is:

```
from lib.google_search_results import GoogleSearchResults
query = GoogleSearchResults({"q": "coffee"})
html_results = query.get_html()
```

More advanced uses are on SERP API Github.